# Error when trying to execute a code?

Tags: java, selenium

I got this error when executing a script . I have upgrade FF(56), Gecko(v0.19) and Selenium 3.6...

This is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("website is opened");
driver.close();
}
}
```

Error in Logs:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path
>   to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver
>   system property; for more information, see
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be
>   downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:754)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:40)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:114)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:329)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:150)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:120)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:98)
>         at god.Testing.main(Testing.java:8)

Comment: Why not set the path before trying to launch the driver?

Comment: Alright, tried  the posiitons of path and launching the driver..successfully opened the facebook but got these errors meantime..

Answer (score 0):

Replace the position of `setProperty()` method, it should before `get()` method

Try this code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("website is opened");
    driver.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Try this code and let me know, it is working fine for me

Comment: Thank you for helping me ..although the browser opens and does it work but got different errors this time.

Comment: 1507418717668 geckodriver INFO geckodriver 0.19.0
1507418717676 geckodriver INFO Listening on 127.0.0.1:15238

Comment: Seems different i will. Try and let you know

Comment: i tried the script and i'm OK now but now 'm having hard time to handle Geolocation  pop up . I tried the script which was posted on this site(THANK YOU) but can still see the pop up and this site is not letting me ask one more question:-(.HELP please.

Comment: Post a different question so we will try

Answer (score 0):

The error we are seeing on the Console as **`IllegalStateException`** is pretty correct and justified.

### Explaination:

In your code block, right in the begining, you have first initialized the **`WebDriver`** instance and casted it to **`FirefoxDriver`** as follows:

```
WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

When this line of code is executed, **`Java Compiler`** have no information about your **`Test Configuration`** of using **`geckodriver.exe`** as the line for **`Test Configuration`** is mentioned later in your program as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Hence, in absence of finding a proper **`driver executable`**, **`Java Compiler`** complains of **`java.lang.IllegalStateException`**.

### Solution:

The solution to your issue would be to rearrange the 2 lines of code as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver  driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```